# how to get all trade history with ccxt for bingx

Tags: python, ccxt

lang:python
os:ubuntu

i want to get all trading history detail like PnL,avg price,trade time and ...

```
bingx = ccxt.bingx({
    'apiKey': config.BINGX_API_KEY,
    'secret': config.BINGX_SECRET_KEY,
})
orders = bingx.fetch_closed_orders('DOGE/USDT:USDT', limit=20)
print(orders)
```

this code is not working for me

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.